# How do I monitor the size of a folder (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor the size of a folder (all files and sub folders). If a certain size is reached there should be some kind of message. The message should be displayed after windows starts up from shut down, hibernation or sleep (or in timed intervals - at least daily).

I would prefer a way that can be achieved with standard windows features, tools or scripts. But if you know 3rd party software that's able to do it, you are welcome to suggest it (if possible with a screen shot and a little bit of explanation). Thanks!

Please note:

- if you suggest 3rd party monitoring software please make sure it can monitor the folder size and trigger the right alarm.
- if you suggest a script a rudimentary example would be nice and is more then enough for me (just so I have a starting point to create it myself)

Comment: You need Windows Server to create quotas on folders. For Windows 7 you can only set them on volumes ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil)).

Comment: @harrymc thanks, I open up the solution scope to scripts as well...

Comment: Scheduled tasks are easily set to run on login, logoff, and at regular intervals. So, write a script using any of the common methods (vbscript, batch, powershell) that checks the size and notifies when it exceeds a given amount, and use scheduled tasks to run it at events and intervals of your choosing.

Comment: @music2myear cmd-batch doesn't seem to be very good to monitor the folder size, I think I'll rather go with vbscript or powershell. Is it possible to schedule tasks for sleep/hibr. since there is no login involved (in my setting the password prompt for reactivation is disabled as well)?

Comment: You can select task triggers based on lots of things, including any event listed in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a powershell script with the following code:

```
if((Get-Item \\server\file).length -gt 1.5GB) {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Folder X has exceeded 1.5GB')
}
```

Then create a scheduled task that runs on login and at regular intervals thereafter that calls this script.

The script checks file or folder size and if it exceeds 1.5GB it triggers a message box with the message.

Answer (score 0):

@music2myear 's post is much better, but mine is a slightly different approach.

Using create a .ps1 (powershell file) with the following:

```
$size = ((Get-ChildItem C:\users\ -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum)
if ($size -gt 3.5GB)
{ 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("C:\users folder is bigger than 3.5 Gb",0,"Done",0x1)
}
```

This will generate a popup saying that the `C:\Users` folder is larger than `3.5 GB` otherwise, will do nothing.
You would then pop this .ps1 file into scheduled tasks to be executed on user login or in the logon script for a user if you are on a domain. (Scheduled task probably easier).